# What happens if Slackjaw is killed in Mission 3?

Tags: dishonored

For the heck of it, after playing through Dishonored with a (nearly) no-kill philosophy, I started a second playthrough of the game, being as ridiculously violent as possible. Therefore, when I got to the Distillery, I cut down all the thugs, *including* Slackjaw. Apparently that's possible.

This begs the question... what's going to happen in Mission 7? He's supposed to show up as Granny Rags' prisoner. Does anybody know if the game takes this into account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I played both styles (kill very few, and kill everyone) and I was quite disappointed at how few changes there were on the Granny Rags storyline.

Firstly, if you kill him before completing his mission, it looks like there's no way to get into the Captain's Chair Hotel, which contains a bone rune. I was trying not to waste time, so I just killed him as soon as I saw him and missed out on the rune. Oh well, no biggie.

Next, you get interesting some new dialog from the Bottle Street Gang member who survived Granny Rags' attack, saying "we had no chance without Slackjaw with us".

When you finally get to Granny Rags, she has Slackjaw's body in her kitchen, still crispy from being cooked in the furnace. I don't know how she recovered his corpse, as I had the skill that turns corpses into ash when I killed Slackjaw. She tells you that you may take his belongings, but to leave the bones for her.

Slackjaw's belongings consist of some coins and the key you require to proceed. If you try to pick up Slackjaw's corpse, Granny Rags attacks you. The rune in the room after Granny Rags' kitchen is still there for the stealing.

I don't know if killing Granny Rags has any effect on the rest of the game - in my stealth playthrough, I used a sleep dart on her but the end-of-level actions list only said that I helped Slackjaw escape. In my psychopath playthrough, I killed her, but I don't think it was mentioned on the end-of-level list.

Comment: @desaivv I'm pretty sure incinerating the cameo and killing her counts as permanently killing her. (You can throw her into her own cauldron, if you knock her out...)

Comment: Thanks for the info BinarySplit. I was very curious on this point, and nobody else seems to have actually gone and killed him (at least, I couldn't find references elsewhere on the internet)

Comment: Actually, there is a way to get into the Captain's chair hotel w/o finishing the mission for Slackjaw. You'll have to go around the back alley in front of the Captain's char hotel door (the alley will be on the street with the searching lights that shoot at you when detected). Save the lady getting hustled for her red elixir.

Answer (score 0):

Granny can Definitely be killed - I literally *just* did it.

It's not easy though. You have to destroy her pendant - I'm pretty sure you have to do the same thing if Slackjaw is already dead and you want to kill her. If you don't want to kill her I have no idea. As long as you're not doing a no-kill game then it's fine - Slackjaw can die early on.